# SNMP Support in Linux for IF-MIB

Tags: linux, network-interface, ip, yocto, snmp

I am trying to setup an SNMP agent in my Linux Box. I installed net-snmp and did some basic config. However while performing snmpget,snmpwalk operations. I am able to get the outputs for only system MIBs. Other details such as interfaces (IF-MIB), IP (IP-MIB) are just empty.

root@local:/# snmpbulkget -v2c  -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2
IF-MIB::ifDescr = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)

Is the population of MIB tables achievable by configurations or do we have to write our own code for the agent to pick and populate these details ?